# Lazy-eval of Racket Expression

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation

I need some help in analayzing an expression in lazy evalutation  :

```
(let ((x (box 1))) (set-box! x (+ (unbox x) 5)) (unbox x))
```

in app-eval the result would be 6 
but i think in lazy evalutationl it will be 1.
thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In `#lang lazy`, if you try to `display` this expression, you get an error message: `force: reentrant promise`.

Comment: @uselpa i don't need to display just to evaluate it and when it try with #lang lazy i'm getting (delay...)

Comment: `display` forces evaluation.